# Unable to locate Element in HTML page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a python selenium script to gather some data from a website and i am unable to select the Search-box where I've to send keys.In the search box i need to key in the name of the dashboard from where i need to extract data.I have tried both class name and css selector selection.

```
    driver.get('https://xyxxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxxyxyxyx')         
    time.sleep(20)
    element = 
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('kuiToolBarSearchBox__input ng- 
    pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    time.sleep(10)
    element.send_keys('XYZ')

    driver.get('https://xyxxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxxyxyxyx')         
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.kuiToolBarSearchBox__input 
    ng- 
    pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    time.sleep(10)
    element.send_keys('XYZ')
```

```html
<input class="kuiToolBarSearchBox__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" type="text" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Filter dashboards" data-test-subj="searchFilter" ng-model="listingController.filter" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: Perhaps try `element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.kuiToolBarSearchBox__input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty.ng-touched')`

Comment: @Justin : I tried that too but no luck.